# What can I use to make my unique music ideas a reality?

Tags: music

I have several different music ideas for my game BGMs, but I do not have the musical skills nor the equipment to make them. The most I can do is beat-box them or make a drum beat (had I a drum). Is there a program or some other way to make my music real?

For instance, I've recently been trying GarageBand's Musical Keyboard to create the music but they don't have the exact beats I'm looking for, like a particular tap of a drum for example.

Comment: -1 not related to game programming at all

Comment: @MaikSemder I could have sworn making the music for your game would fall under game development

Comment: @MaikSemder That does not matter. This is the **Game Development** Stack Exchange, it should realistically cover all the practices of Game Development. Not just programming.

Comment: Better to be migrated to avp.stackexchange.com although most likely would get closed there too. Just as a quick tip, if you're starting out with music production (it doesn't matter if it's for a game, a movie or just for the hell of it) check out FruityLoops.

Comment: So your looking for software on a mac?

Comment: Actually I think a better place would be music.stackexchange.com

Comment: Making the music does fall under game development. Game Developers, especially indie developers who are forced to wear many hats, may have some advice that could be particularly helpful to other game developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating your music, the first thing I am going to recommend is of course [FL Studio](http://flstudio.com). I mean, it's really nice, and as flexible as you would need it to be. It comes pre-loaded with all kinds of sample instruments and getting more is as simple as loading a VST.

---

Now to answer the broader question here. "I have an idea for music, but I don't know how to make it happen" there is a growing market with a (currently limited, but growing) selection of tools.

First off **[UJAM](http://ujam.com)**. It's insanely fun to play with, and with the proper work it can make some really decent tracks. It's as simple to use as **singing** or humming the tune that you want. From there you can convert it into a variety of instruments* and use a number of (last I check) growing effects to mix and 'master' the track.

Then, if you have one, I recommend looking at **[Garage Band on the iPad](http://www.apple.com/ipad/from-the-app-store/garageband.html)**. While not as full featured as it's sibling. It definitely makes creating music quickly a priority. It has a variety of smart instruments that can be used to quickly put together a track with limited effort. And if you check the link, it has drum kit's built in that just might solve your current issue (I was able to get rim shots out of it, and I think there is minor tonal differences when you strike in different locations).

There are no doubt more, but those three together let me put together all of my proto-music for all the prototypes that I work on.

Comment: * seriously. I've put together guitar tracks and piano tracks that are far more technically complicated than what I am currently capable of.

Comment: UJAM and FL Studio seem to be the best for the job from what I have been seeing. I've already made an account and tinkered with UJAM already. I'm loving it so far. I'm going to try out FL Studio soon. Hopefully it ends up being better than UJAM. UJAM can get a bit annoying since its a website-application.

Answer (score 6):

I am no music guy. But, have you heard of [FL Studio](http://flstudio.image-line.com/) & its free alternate [LMMS - Linux MultiMedia Studio](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/)

Sorry, dont know much about it. Its better if you talk to musician.

You can give it a try here http://music.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like Ableton Live, it's very easy to get started with and it comes with a massive supply of loops, instruments and effects.

www.ableton.com

I'd say https://video.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to post this question. 
Also, there are multitudes of sample packs available, you can utalise these in conjunction with a good sequencer such as Ableton, Logic, Cubase, Reaper, Fruity loops, or even garage band.

Google "sample packs" along with the genre your interested in, so something like classical strings, Jazz trumpets, hip-hop drums etc...

Comment: FYI - reaper is a free, fully featured music production suite. It's very impressive, but if you have the cash Ableton Live is still an awesome way to go for fast easy music production. Personally I use both Ableton Live and Logic Studio, with various plug-ins and sample packs.

Comment: Havn't used ableton. How it it comparing with FL Studio?

Comment: The beauty of ableton is the session view IMO. Add a number of channels, drag and drop audio loops, MIDI patterns (with associated AU/VST's) straight into the cells, then hit record and jam with them kind of like an MPC if you've ever used one of those. It can be as simple or as complicated as you want it to be. check it on youtube, or download the demo. I use it for live performance, just hack up all my multi-track audio into loops of various sizes, then remix them live on stage, great fun! It manipulates Audio like its MIDI, in real time.

Comment: Seems like its focused towards real time stuff.

Comment: This is old, but I still find it impressive: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfBh3lZZi8Q that's one half of it, it has a whole arrange section too.  I use it for live stuff mostly

Comment: @mal Thaks for the heads up about [reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/), I'm gonna try it tonight, though it only seems that a trial version is free?

Comment: it used to be totally free, but to the best of my knowledge it only reminds you to register and pay, I don't think it locks you out. Having said that, I'm a firm believer in paying if you think it's useful. :-D

Comment: Reaper's extremely cheap at $40 for a licence anyway

Answer (score -3):

The world needs a game with beatbox music as a backing track, make it!  (I made my sound effects orally to get started in development faster.)

Comment: Not an answer. -1.